# Performance optimisation of my XSLT1

Tags: xslt, optimization, biztalk

I'm looking to optimise this XSLT slightly if anyone can spot any improvements / recommendations?

I receive an XML file which follows along this sort of format:

```
<TransfersToComplete>
    <TransfersForFees>
        <Transfer>
            <PlayerID>1234</PlayerID>
            <ClubJoiningID>4444</ClubJoiningID>
            <FeeInPounds>1200000</FeeInPounds>
        </Transfer>
        <Transfer>
            <PlayerID>3835</PlayerID>
            <ClubJoiningID>4444</ClubJoiningID>
            <FeeInPounds>5000000</FeeInPounds>
        </Transfer>
        <Transfer>
            <PlayerID>17118</PlayerID>
            <ClubJoiningID>5229</ClubJoiningID>
            <FeeInPounds>18000000</FeeInPounds>
        </Transfer>
    </TransfersForFees>
    <FreeAgencyTransfers>
        <FreeTransfer>
            <PlayerID>42323</PlayerID>
            <ClubJoiningID>332</ClubJoiningID>
        </FreeTransfer>
    </FreeAgencyTransfers>
</TransfersToComplete>
```

I also have another XML file that contains the list of the 'active' clubs (ie ones being controlled by players rather than AI)

```
    <ActiveClubs>
<Club><ClubID>1234</ClubID></Club>
    <Club><ClubID>4482</ClubID></Club>
    </ActiveClubs>
```

I've joined these in a dual input map as part of a Biztalk Solution, so the input document looks something like this:

```
<Root>
    <InputMessage0>
        <ActiveClubs>
            <Club>
                <ClubID>1234</ClubID>
            </Club>
            <Club>
                <ClubID>4482</ClubID>
            </Club>
        </ActiveClubs>
    </InputMessage0>
    <InputMessage1>
        <TransfersToComplete>
            <TransfersForFees>
                <Transfer>
                    <PlayerID>1234</PlayerID>
                    <ClubJoiningID>4444</ClubJoiningID>
                    <FeeInPounds>1200000</FeeInPounds>
                </Transfer>
                <Transfer>
                    <PlayerID>3835</PlayerID>
                    <ClubJoiningID>4444</ClubJoiningID>
                    <FeeInPounds>5000000</FeeInPounds>
                </Transfer>
                <Transfer>
                    <PlayerID>17118</PlayerID>
                    <ClubJoiningID>5229</ClubJoiningID>
                    <FeeInPounds>18000000</FeeInPounds>
                </Transfer>
            </TransfersForFees>
            <FreeAgencyTransfers>
                <FreeTransfer>
                    <PlayerID>42323</PlayerID>
                    <ClubJoiningID>332</ClubJoiningID>
                </FreeTransfer>
            </FreeAgencyTransfers>
        </TransfersToComplete>
    </InputMessage1>
</Root>
```

I dont want every player on the game to see the full workings of every transfer, so I restrict to only their own clubs, my XSLT is as follows:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/*[1]/ActiveClubs/Club">
<xsl:variable name ="clubId" select="current()/ClubID/text()"/>
<...CallTemplate...>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there a way I can optimise that for-each, and how does it help? I'm seeing my CPU slowly getting chewed up as the number of active clubs grows so I assume this is a partial cause?

EDIT:

Expected Output would be variable ClubId first time around to be 1234, second time 4482

In my example above (2 active clubs) I see little/no performance degredation - its when I get to 40 and beyond...

In terms of showing the rest of the XSLT - This is the template it calls:

```
<xsl:call-template name="DoPaidTransfers">
  <xsl:with-param name="var:ClubId" select="$clubId"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Which is:

```
  <xsl:template name="DoPaidTransfers">
<xsl:param name="var:ClubId"/>
<responseCode><xsl:value-of select="CSharpCodeCall:DoPaidTransfers($clubId)"/></responseCode>
</xsl:template>
```

My C# code writes them to a DB, returning a code for success, and this is passed on elsewhere through the environment.
As I say, it works as expected but I see significant performance loss when ramping up the number of clubs that are active.

Comment: I think you could make use of **xsl:key** here. Could you show your full XSLT, and your expected output in this case, as this will help us fully understand and analyse the situation. Thanks!

Comment: @TimC - done that for you - anything else I can show to help?

Comment: Hmmm.. I am not sure the issue is with XSLT here. If the DB is being called for each club, then you will need to make sure the DB procedure is as optimised as possible. Is there a possibility of calling the DB just once, but passing in all active clubs at once (for example, as a comma-delimited list?)

Comment: ive checked that though by load testing the C# class in isolation and its fine - no loss of service etc there or even slower result times, which is why i've looked at the XSLT...

Comment: "_My C# code writes them to a DB_" - How does the C# code determine what "them" is? Can you show your C# code? I'm assuming it's gathering the transfer data based on the `$clubId`. This is most likely the piece that's inefficient. Like @TimC said, this is probably something that xsl:key could help with; have the XSLT gather the data to be uploaded and have the C# code only do the db write.

Comment: Just noticed the date on the question/comments/answer lol. Feel free to ignore my previous comment (unless you're still interested in possibly solving this old problem).

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the whole xslt, please?

I'm pretty sure the performance issue isn't in the piece of xslt you've shown.

I ran the below xslt through the ms xsl processor in VS, on a list of 2000 Active Clubs, whilst simulating your DB writes call by introducing a 10ms delay with `Thread.Sleep()` in C# script, and the results were:

> Stylesheet load time: 25.12 ms 
>   Stylesheet execution time: 20125 ms

i.e. 2000 clubs in 125ms if you exclude the Sleeps.

So the issue is surely somewhere else, e.g. how does the data in `TransfersToComplete` factor into the map?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:CSharpCodeCall="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:var="YourNSForVariables"
                exclude-result-prefixes="var msxsl CSharpCodeCall"
                >
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[1]/ActiveClubs/Club">
            <xsl:variable name ="clubId" select="current()/ClubID/text()"/>
            <club>
                <clubid>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$clubId"/>
                </clubid>
                <xsl:call-template name="DoPaidTransfers">
                    <xsl:with-param name="var:ClubId" select="$clubId"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </club>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="DoPaidTransfers">
        <xsl:param name="var:ClubId"/>
        <responseCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="CSharpCodeCall:DoPaidTransfers($var:ClubId)"/>
        </responseCode>
    </xsl:template>

    <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="CSharpCodeCall">
        <![CDATA[
        // I've stubbed this as a 10ms delay
        public System.String DoPaidTransfers(System.String clubId)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            return "Transferred";
        }
        ]]>
    </msxsl:script>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```